# How to distinguish keypresses from different keyboards in Windows

Tags: windows, input, keyboard, keyboard-events

I am accustomed to detecting keyboard key presses via Windows messages, but there does not appear to be a way to distinguish between presses of the same key by different keyboards in the case when multiple keyboards are connected.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx

Is there an easy way to do this in Windows at user level?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean distinguish keyboards within a single login session (as opposed to Windows Multipoint Server). In which case the answer is no, in the sense that there aren't documented Win32 APIs to do this. However it is possible, because Multipoint does distinguish keyboards to support multiple local users.

Comment: Thank you Xpw; Requirements have now changed, and I've since decided to take a different route with this. If you want to make that an answer, I'll mark it best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean distinguish keyboards within a single login session (as opposed to Windows Multipoint Server). In which case the answer is no, in the sense that there aren't documented Win32 APIs to do this. However it is possible, because Multipoint does distinguish keyboards to support multiple local users.